# What creational, structural, and behavioural design patterns exist besides the GoF ones?

Tags: design-patterns

Are there any creational, structural or behavioural design patterns that exist outside of the ones defined in the GoF book?

Comment: Yes, but i do not know a good reference. Maybe you can start by checking out the patterns at the bottom of this page: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entwurfsmuster_%28Buch%29
I did not find an English version but I think you can use the keywords in the bottom table

Comment: I've already seen these. Anymore?